# CoreData - (Performance) Considerations for frequent data

Tags: ios, performance, core-data

**Background**

We have an app that receives sensor data at 100 Hz. Each sensor data contains three floats. Occasionally (max 1/s) some other metadata may be received that needs to be saved as well. The UI displays the latest 1000 sensor values in a graph. There are no undo-requirements - all received data must be saved to file. Each session lasts for at least 10 min, but may (in rare circumstances and mostly due to mistake) be up to an hour.

**Current approach**

*Model:* `SensorData` has a many-to-one relationship with `Session`. `MetaData` has a many-to-one relationship with `Session`.

*CoreData:* Set up a UIManagedDocument to handle CoreData. One MOC on main thread with a child MOC on a private queue. The child MOC creates the objects and add them to the object graph. Every 100th data, save child MOC. Once session ends, save main MOC to PSC.

*Edit:* The problem I have with the current approach is that saving in the child MOC lags behind, which means not all data has been processed when session ends and processing time increases with run time.

**Questions**

- Is it feasible to use CoreData as storage mechanism at ~100 Hz, or should I look at some alternative (like saving to a csv-file)?
- What considerations must I take to ensure proper/optimal performance?
- I have had performance issues with saves taking a long time and blocking UI. How can I avoid this? I.e. what saving policy should I use?
- Drawbacks and advantages of current approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Core Data can do this.

You could use Marcus Zarra's approach of three contexts to make sure the actual save also happens in the background.

```
RootContext (background) saves to persistent store  ---> is parent of
MainContext (main thread) to update the UI          ---> is parent of one or more
WorkerContext (background) to create new data from sensor
```

You could then actually save more frequently in the background to the persistent store directly without impacting UI responsiveness. This should also improve memory usage. Saving the worker context will push the changes to the UI which can be updated accordingly.

For performance make sure you batch save - with three floats I would estimate every 1.000 to 5.000 records or so (you need to experiment to find the optimal value).

Turn off the undo manager.  (`context.undoManager = nil`)

Another consideration would be to maybe think hard about what you want to show in the UI and perhaps calculate values to display on the fly and send that to the UI, rather than have the UI rely on the entire session's data set to update itself.

Comment: Core Data can definitely do this (and it has been done in the past at this rate). Save the child frequently (1 per second is more than enough for humans normally) and save to disk infrequently (every couple of seconds) and you should not have memory issues or data loss issues (unless the app crashes).

Comment: Ok, a fair bit later I got this working. I was doing two mistakes. 1) I was using a UIDocument that was created on the Main Queue for the root context. 2) While I only saved in batches, I was not creating the entities in batches. However, this was on a different project and I'm not using the MainContext.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up against exactly this issue, in an elaboration of [this project](https://github.com/foundry/MagnetoMeter).

My task is to record live sensor data from (for example) Core Motion and Core Location at rates up to 100Hz whilst simultaneously running a smoothly animating interface which can inolve any of Core Graphics, Core Animation, OpenGL and live video. There are ~20-40 separate data items to track, mostly doubles but one or two strings, and they do not all arrive at the same sync rate.

*Any* hold-up during saves, however slight, will have an immediate hit on the interface.

I was interested to compare using Core Data against writing directly to a SQL database (using sqlite3). My personal experience so far (this is a work in progress) is that the SQL approach is much better suited to this type of problem than Core data. In fact its not really what Core Data was optimised for (which is rather to manage complex document object models with undo, persistence and efficient faulting). The Core Data model almost *assumes* that persistent saves will be prohibitively slow (for example, saving to iCloud), and much of it's engineering is designed to offer solutions to *that* problem.

I have tried various core data patterns, backgrounding, parent/child contexts, sync, async, batching saves ... and invariably i find a noticeable stutter whenever a persistent save actually occurs.

The SQL approach, on the other hand, is simple to understand, efficent and completely free of noticable glitches.

It may well be that I have not arrived at the optimal core data pattern for this problem (and I will be digging deeper into this, as it is an interesting edge case). However I would definitely suggest a look at the direct-to-SQL approach if that makes sense for you in your broader app context.

In slightly different data-streaming use-cases (for example, a 250-500Hz signal delivered over bluetooth) I have opted for the kind of signal-processing tricks used by audio interfaces - *ring buffers*, queues and callbacks can become very useful as your data rate goes up. At some point the data rate will get too high for a database-writing process to keep up: then - as you suggest - saving directly to file will be more efficient. You can always read the data back out of files at some later point and populate the database (or core data) when sampling is not taking place.

Matt Gallagher made a nice comparision of Core Data and Databases. 
[It's a fairly old piece, but the patterns haven't changed so it is still relevant](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html). There's also useful little (and similarly-aged) discussion [here](http://postgresql.nabble.com/High-Frequency-Inserts-to-Postgres-Database-vs-Writing-to-a-File-td2075457.html) on the benefits of flat file over database writing with high-frequency streams.

Comment: Thanks for following up here! I never resolved the issue, but instead dropped the feature. The reason for using CoreData is that much of the other data is quite suitable for CoreData (much of it is displayed in table views and the likes). Please post any updates as you explore!

Comment: @T'n'E, I am having a similar experience as this answer. Were you really able to record at 100Hz? I have almost the identical problem. How did you do it? I'm not clear on your comment on Dec 8 '15.

Comment: Sort of. We never needed to display the data in the end, only save it. We can do that successfully. It requires some care with threading and buffering, so make sure you have a design on how to process your data. But I would take @Mundi's advice and consider not having the UI read from CoreData, but rather process that on the fly.

Comment: The trouble I had with @Mundi's advice was that I have one-to-many relationships set up, which forces all the objects to load into memory. I spoke with an Apple engineer at WWDC2020, and he discouraged me from using child context, and he recommended that I use [NSBatchInsertRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchinsertrequest) instead, which worked. This works because objects are written immediately to the Sqlite database without loading into memory. The downside is that I had to dismantle the one-to-many relationships.